# SQL Server : IF NOT EXISTS MULTIPLE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, insert

I need to insert multiple rows into a table. I'm doing this by selecting the rows from another table and inserting them into the desired table.

The problem is one or two of the rows I need to insert might already exist. How can I do a `IF NOT EXISTS` on an insert that is inserting many rows like in this example below ?

```
BEGIN TRAN
    INSERT INTO [main].[dbo].[product_usa] 
        SELECT *
        FROM [main].[dbo].[product_mxo]
        WHERE tag_key IN ('15652', '16161', '11431', '16214',  '16215',  '16216', 
                          '16213', '16217', '16218',  '16222') 
          AND edition_key = '1'  
          AND product_key = '1'
-- COMMIT 
-- ROLLBACK
```

Answer (score 0):

if `tag_key` is pk in both  `product_usa` and `product_mxo` just need add `exists` to validate the tag_key isn't already there.

```
INSERT INTO [main].[dbo].[product_usa] 
    SELECT *
    FROM   [main].[dbo].[product_mxo] mxo
    WHERE  tag_key IN 
        ('15652', '16161', '11431',
         '16214', '16215', '16216', 
         '16213', '16217', '16218', 
         '16222') 
     AND edition_key = '1'  
     AND product_key = '1'
     AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                     FROM [main].[dbo].[product_usa] usa
                     WHERE us.tag_key = mxo.tag_key)
```

Comment: 0 rows affected. I'm not sure how to expand on this, but there are rows that should be affected.

Comment: The query looks ok. Try `SELECT * FROM [main].[dbo].[product_usa] usa WHERE  tag_key IN 
        ('15652', '16161', '11431',
         '16214', '16215', '16216', 
         '16213', '16217', '16218', 
         '16222') `  bring any result? Then do the same with `mxo`

Answer (score 0):

You can add `EXISTS`like this.

```
BEGIN TRAN
INSERT INTO [main].[dbo].[product_usa] 
    SELECT *
    FROM   [main].[dbo].[product_mxo]
    WHERE  tag_key IN 
    (
        '15652', 
        '16161',
        '11431',
        '16214', 
        '16215', 
        '16216', 
        '16213', 
        '16217', 
        '16218', 
        '16222'
    ) AND edition_key = '1'  AND product_key = '1'
    AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [main].[dbo].[product_usa] WHERE /* Column Comparison */ )
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming tag_key is the primary or unique key you could do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO [main].[dbo].[product_usa] 
    SELECT *
    FROM   [main].[dbo].[product_mxo] t
    WHERE  tag_key IN 
    (
        '15652', 
        '16161',
        '11431',
        '16214', 
        '16215', 
        '16216', 
        '16213', 
        '16217', 
        '16218', 
        '16222'
    ) AND edition_key = '1'  AND product_key = '1'
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [main].[dbo].[product_usa] x WHERE t.tag_key = x.tag_key)
```

If you want all records that don't exist just get rid of your other where conditions

```
INSERT INTO [main].[dbo].[product_usa] 
    SELECT *
    FROM   [main].[dbo].[product_mxo] t
    WHERE
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [main].[dbo].[product_usa] x WHERE t.tag_key = x.tag_key)
```

Comment: Same as @juan solution, 0 rows affected.

Comment: @John yes he and I answered at same time but they are not exactly the same answer.  reading comments on his answer you should probably consider the second part of my answer.  But you need to explain what it is you want.  Such as "I am trying to insert every row from product_mxo into product_usa" that doesn't exist the primary key is tag_key or another column.  Or I am trying to synch the tables, or I am trying to insert every product that meets xyz criteria and doesn't exist.... if you are not able to get the result you want you more than likely are filtering out too much or incorrect where

Answer (score 0):

Do a left outer join with the target table on tag_key and check for nulls.

```
INSERT INTO [main].[dbo].[product_usa] 
SELECT m.*
FROM   [main].[dbo].[product_mxo] m
LEFT OUTER JOIN [main].[dbo].[product_usa] u
ON u.tag_key = m.tag_key
WHERE  m.tag_key IN 
(
    '15652', 
    '16161',
    '11431',
    '16214', 
    '16215', 
    '16216', 
    '16213', 
    '16217', 
    '16218', 
    '16222'
) AND m.edition_key = '1'  AND m.product_key = '1' AND u.tag_key IS NULL
```

Comment: Sorry... you were asking about NOT EXISTS. While my answer will solve the problem you describe, it does not use the tools you asked about. My mistake...